# Reporting for a small-scale (but growing) internet company

Tags: jasper-reports, reporting, birt, pentaho

So I'm working for a company that is in the affiliate business. I built a small web application for them that fetches data, does the accounting and stuff like that.

Now that everything works nicely my customer - of course - wants to do data-mining on the gathered data, like filtering, aggregating, plotting and all the like. Naturally - as a lazy developer at least - I have no interest in implementing that kind of stuff by hand, so I wonder if there is a lean, but still powerful open source reporting software that I could use for that?

My criterias for such a software are as follows:

- reports should be easy to write / code for me as developer and ideally also be kept in a format that could easily be kept in a version control system
- data source is JSON, but that could be transformed to XML as well
- data grouping, joining, filtering, calculations, etc. should be possible (and no, no XSLT :)
- a module for report visualization exists, ideally self-deployable to the web
- visual reporting design is a plus, but not a need
- platform is irrelevant, as long as it is easy to setup and manage

I realized that there are basically three big OS "competitors" in the market, BIRT, Pentaho and JasperReports. I'm totally unsure if such a tool is the right choice for us just *now* , as they're all feel a little oversized in terms of features and complexity...

Comment: Crystal isn't open source. Were you thinking of JasperReports?

Answer (score 1):

A quick review on Pentaho (Pentaho BI Platform in general, not only scoped to reporting) based on your points. Of course the community edition (open-source) has served the community well and may already suit your needs, but the enterprise edition (which requires a license) has more additional features such as: support, enterprise repository with third party security, revision management and collaboration (locking and so forth), integrated interface for scheduling, the Data Integration Server to do the scheduling and run the enterprise repository, documentation (Knowledge Base, manual).

Of course other resources can be found in the community wiki [here](http://wiki.pentaho.com/display/COM/Community+Wiki+Home) but it is still a working copy.

Now back to your points.

> - *reports should be easy to write / code for me as developer and
>     ideally also be kept in a format that could easily be kept in a
>     version control system*

If you wish to code for the reports, as far as I've used it, the report documentation are quite easy to understand (found also at the wiki). You can also find samples on the web. It is kind of similar to JasperReports.

> - *data source is JSON, but that could be transformed to XML as well*

The Pentaho Report Designer (will be explained in your visual reporting tool point below) can recognize XML datasource types, but I haven't worked with a JSON datasource type.

> - *data grouping, joining, filtering, calculations, etc. should be
>     possible (and no, no XSLT :)*

You can use the Pentaho Data Integration of the Pentaho platform to do transformations, mostly which you are asking. It has a variety of jobs to execute and you just have to chain them together.

> - *a module for report visualization exists, ideally self-deployable to
>     the web*

Yes a module for report visualization exists, and it is within the Pentaho BI Server (a webapp, which can recognize all of your Pentaho solutions. To take for example your report, you just have to put the report in the solution repository (which the BI server connects to, it's just a simple folder), and when you launch it in the BI Server, it will show you a preview of your report, along with selected parameters that you wish to display to manipulate the data in the report.

> - *visual reporting design is a plus, but not a need*

Pentaho has a reporting tool called Pentaho Report Designer. It is similar to JasperReports Visual Studio, and it is pretty much easy to learn and use.

> - *platform is irrelevant, as long as it is easy to setup and manage*

The platform is easy to setup and manage.

Comment: Thanks for the writeup. That all sounds nice and promising - like from a whitepaper - but I kind of miss any controversial or even negative points of Pentaho - I'm sure there are...?! Or is this tool just better than sliced bread?

Comment: Hmm, maybe the negative points are lack of support (on the community edition). It all depends on your comprehension maybe. So far I haven't had any experiences where I've had trouble, maybe integrating it to 3rd party apps?

Comment: @tommyd: There is a comparison of the features of BIRT, Jasspersoft and Pentaho here: http://www.innoventsolutions.com/birt-jasper-pentaho-comparison-matrix.html

Comment: @MarkBannister That is one awesome find.

Answer (score 0):

Since this is all web-based, have you looked into any JS libraries?

You didn't include any as an option, but I thought I would put a plug in for one particularly just because I've used BIRT exclusively for years, and I've used Jasper reports a little but I've dropped both in favor of the ExtJS library.

The ExtJS charts were very easy to customize and they had nice animation right out of the box - visually they beat the BIRT and Jasper charts hands down in my opinion. The ExtJS grids have excellent features for grouping, sorting and filtering built-in along with other plug-ins for exporting to excel, paging, etc. Along with the rest of things the library offers like drag and drop support, synchronous loading of JS classes, etc.

My work is all for internal use so the OS version worked out fine for me.

It was easy enough to use it without the designer, but they do have one.

Comment: Its actually not so much about visualization, but more about data aggregation (based on business logic) and filtering. And I don't want to do that solely client-side, because I'd have to transfer too much to the client.